# List-style-type does not remove dot

Tags: html, css

I am trying to style my drupal site, and am working my way through the site (beginning with the main menu)... But I am running into problems.

It won't allow me to remove the dots made by `<ul>` using `list-style-type: none;`

```
<nav>
    <div class="region region-navigation">
    <div id="block-system-main-menu" class="block block-system block-menu">
    <div class="content">
         <ul class="menu">
               <li class="first leaf">
                      <a href="/node/3" title="About us">About</a>
               </li>
               <li class="last leaf">
                      <a href="/" class="active">Home</a>
               </li>
         </ul>  
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

style.css:

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

I had more CSS than what I just posted initially, but I removed massive amounts to try and start from scratch. Doing the above doesn't even work. It still displays dots next to the links.

Comment: Yes, [it does](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ezp68d12/).

Comment: If this is specific to Drupal, that should be said in the *question*. As asked, the question presents a non-reproduceable problem: nothing in the code included creates any “dots”.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having problem in drupal? Then do like this:

```
ul.menu{
  list-style: none !important;
}

ul.menu li{
  list-style: none !important;
}
```

Which makes sure to remove the list-style-type.

Comment: Why? Is this a Drupal-specific thing? (I'm not intending to disagree, or criticise; I'm genuinely curious.)

Comment: Yes, there is some massive things in drupal which don't allow to remove simply. And I had faced the same problem before.

Comment: That worked. Does drupal specifically not allow me to change the CSS for the menu?

Comment: You should be doing ul.menu{} instead of ul{}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66870/discussion-between-user3407764-and-bhojendra-c-link-nepal).